# Why is my Flutter IOS App crashing on startup with nor error details from Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, crash

I recently got a Mac to develop Apps for IOS. Now after starting my App on a simulated IOS device it immediately crashes after the startup screen.

Output of flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm, locale
    de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /library/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (3 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/melvinmorawietz/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/melvinmorawietz/Downloads/Visual Studio
      Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile)     • DF7842B0-402A-4860-8B80-D8AE1676FA60 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 7666C846-C715-49CE-B18E-64FA6ADE0F11 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                •
      darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml (for possible IOS and Android problems because of packages?):

```
name: projekteinstein
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.0.0"

dependencies:
  auto_route: ^5.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0+1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dartz: ^0.10.0
  faker: ^2.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.5
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
  kt_dart: ^0.10.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  salomon_bottom_bar: ^3.3.1
  supercharged: ^2.1.1
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  auto_route_generator: ^5.0.2
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.9
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  freezed: ^2.1.0+1
  json_serializable: ^6.0.1
  lint: ^1.7.2

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#2E2C2D"
  image: assets/splash.png

flutter:
  generate: true

  uses-material-design: true
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I already tried to delete the whole IOS folder and deleting the pubspec.lock file.
In Xcode the IOS Deployment Target is 11.0

Comment: You can try open the project in xcode (ios/Runner.xcworkspace). There might be some licences you might need to accept. Anyways, you can run the app from there and you will see the crash logs in xcode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem. If anyone else has a similar issue, don't forget to check the stack trace in Xcode when launching from vscode.

I found the following stack trace:

```
Runner[36150:329595] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSServicesException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'
```

And I realized I forgot to configure the api key for the Google Maps package. After looking up the official documentation I found the following solution.

To set up, specify your API key in the application delegate ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

Or in your swift code, specify your API key in the application delegate ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR KEY HERE")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```